# Creating a validation in PL/SQL

Tags: validation, plsql

How to validate an order? It can only be validated if the order (table orders) isn't bigger than the quantity already in stock (table products). They are in 2 separate tables, as mentioned between paranthesis. This is what I could think of.

```
declare prod number;  order number;
begin
select qty into prod from products;
end;

begin
select qty into order from orders;
end;
if order <= prod then 
 return true;
else
 return false;
end if;
```

Comment: besides the obvious improvements to that code, it seems that would work. It all depends on how and where you wish to implement this

Comment: An anonymous block can't 'return' anything, so even when you fix the syntax errors (you have a stray `begin` and two `end`s, and you are missing a final `end`) and add some sort of `where` clause and exception handling around your queries (just in case you ever have more than one product or order) you'll need to decide what you want it to actually do.

Answer (score 2):

Try to don't use variables which are "key words" like "ORDER" or something else, because your statement wouldn't work in some cases. Just set prefix for them like - l_order (local variable) or v_order (variable). And you also probably need to use exception when no data found, so it would be like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_enough_product RETURN BOOLEAN AS
  l_prod  NUMBER;
  l_ORDER NUMBER;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT qty
      INTO l_prod
      FROM products;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      l_prod := 0;
  END;

  BEGIN
    SELECT qty
      INTO l_ORDER
      FROM orders;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      l_ORDER := 0;
  END;
  IF l_ORDER <= l_prod THEN
    RETURN TRUE;
  ELSE
    RETURN FALSE;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: That still seems to be two and a half blocks, and `l_order` is only defined in the first one.

Comment: yeah, writing it in notepad

Comment: I used this code and tried it but it gives me an error: 

ORA-06550: line 1, column 119: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge

BTW, thanks for your answer. I really appreciate you trying to help me.

Comment: I replaced the first line of the code with declare. The code is being validated but during execution the following error occurs: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error ORA-06512: at line 14 ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows ... what might be the cause of that?

Comment: 1) If you cant create function, that you cant use RETURN also. You need to replace it on something else, maybe on `dbms_output.put_line('TRUE')`, `dbms_output.put_line('FALSE')`  2) You didn't provide any information about your tables (describe structure & data). So I guess you need condition for tables like `SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE SOMETHING = SOMETHING` and you need input parameters because of that. So you definitely need function for this purpose